# Left panel on Area 51 went ballistic

Tags: support, area-51, firefox

Something may have happened to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) within the last 24 hours (it was fine when I checked yesterday). With no known change to my setup (for example, it is still [Firefox 11.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox#Version_11)) I now get:

[image: Screenshot of the left panel that used to be all alone on the left.]

Is this a bug?

Comment: OK, a better title may be in order.

Comment: No repro in FireFox 10 or Chrome 20 (updating FireFox to 11 right now).  **Edit:** Ok, so that update took me to FireFox 13 (who knew!).  Still no problems for me.

Comment: No repro IE 8, has been fine all day

Comment: Zooming in makes the panel go to the left (conversely it should be reproducible by zooming out). It may not be a bug after all. (I have set 'toolkit.zoomManager.zoomValues' to a custom value in order to be able to have more fine-grained zooming,  "0.300,0.341,0.387,0.440,0.500,0.538,0.579,0.623,0.670,0.700,0.732,0.765,0.800,0.824,0.849,0.874,0.900,0.924,0.949,0.974,1.000,1.024,1.049,1.074,1.100,1.124,1.149,1.174,1.200,1.231,1.263,1.296,1.330,1.371,1.412,1.456,1.500,1.548,1.597,1.648,1.700,1.770,1.844,1.920,2.000,2.093,2.191,2.293,2.400,2.538,2.683,2.837,3.000".)

Comment: I can repro when zooming in Firefox but not in Chrome or IE9. So I call this a Firefox bug.

Comment: This is a question for http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com. They have the "area51-meta" tag for these questions.

Answer (score 3):

1. It can be due to the fact that `css` could not be loaded completely due to slow internet speed.
2. Try clearing the `cache` or Restart your `Browser` or restart your machine and make sure the `cache` is cleared before checking next time.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How exactly is the cache cleared? Menu Tools -> Clear Recent History?

Comment: Press Ctrl + Shift + Delete

Comment: That seems to be the keyboard shortcut for menu Tools -> Clear Recent History

Comment: This will do cache clearing as well....

Comment: can you use hard refresh by using ctrl + F5

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't make any difference in this case (and I wouldn't expect it to).

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments to the question, this can happen to Area 51 by zooming out (accidentally hitting Ctrl and scroll wheeling is the easiest way to do it by accident). Firefox helpfully remembers your zoom level for a website, which will make the problem persistent.

Hitting `Ctrl+0` resets the zoom level and hopefully solves your problem.